# Log file includes field: "lsid"

Tags: mongodb

I have the following log row in my Mongodb log file:

> 2019-09-28T14:13:35.668+0000 I COMMAND  [conn19] command shop.$cmd
>   command: update { update: "Task", ordered: true, $db: "shop", lsid: {
>   id: UUID("04c9ce6d-af4b-49b8-a351-d38ee3f2b12a") } } numYields:0
>   reslen:44 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3, w: 3 } }, Database:
>   { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } },
>   Metadata: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_msg 923ms

I cannot find any information about the "lsid" field that is in the log. Can anyone explain what it is and how it can help me understand this command log? I have many rows that have it.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: It's Server session ID. Read [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/server-sessions/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/server-sessions/)